# Devise: restricting page access using user attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, attributes

Relatively new to rails, I've got a simple web app using **Devise** for user authentication.  One attribute is an `:admin` boolean, set `nil` for most users, and I will change to `true` manually in the console for the few users who will need to have administrative access.

**My question is**:  How should I restrict access to a particular page to those who have admin access marked as `true`?

I've attempted some of that logic in my `pages_controller`, but it doesn't seem to redirect me as desired (referring to the `user_list` section):

```
  class PagesController < ApplicationController
        before_action :authenticate_user!, :except => [:welcome]

  def welcome
     #code removed for brevity's sake
  end

  def dashboard
    #ditto
  end

  def user_list
    unless 
     current_user.admin == true
        redirect_to pages_dashboard_path
    else    
      @users = Users.all
    end

  end
end
```

Any suggestions on my goal of redirecting or otherwise restricting access to my `user_list` page would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: redirect_to pages_dashboard_path and return.

Answer (score 0):

in your controller you can do something like this

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def user_list
    if current_user.admin == true
      @users = Users.all
    else
      render :not_an_admin 
    end
  end
end
```

You can not send them to the same page that they dont have access

You can choose to render a new view

Answer (score 0):

In your `user_list` method, model name should be `singular`.

```
def user_list
 unless 
   current_user.admin == true
    redirect_to pages_dashboard_path
 else    
   @users = User.all
 end
end
```